# How do I validate HTML with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to verify that a string is valid HTML, like the [W3C Service](https://validator.w3.org/) does. I specifically don't want any browser corrections (like closing open tags), which precludes options that create DOM elements and read the HTML from them. It will run very frequently, so I really need to run it locally. Libraries are OK, jQuery is OK.

Edit #1: I'm asking about HTML validation, not form or input validation.

Edit #2: What I need is basically a Javascript implementation of the [Nu HTML Checker](https://github.com/validator/validator).

Comment: validation is a very broad topic. String contains, date format, number format, string length, phone number, currency, etc. Way too broad

Comment: I'm not asking about form validation, I'm asking about W3C-style validation, as specified in my question. If you type an HTML string into it, it tells you whether or not the string is valid HTML- period. How is that broad?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Kyle is right: There's nothing broad about "how to validate HTML" unless you're worried about VERSIONS of HTML. If you specifically validate that a text file is, for instance, HTML5, that's a VERY specific ask. It looks like all the "too broad" votes were because everyone assumed he meant "INPUT validation," which he explained that he didn't.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim this was 4 years ago

Answer (score 2):

Provided you're running *node.js* or *python* on the server side you can use a library like [html5-lint](https://github.com/mozilla/html5-lint) by Mozilla to do all the heavy lifting for you. And for the *java* world there is a similar library [jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) and there are countless of similar libraries out there.

Comment: Ideally it would run client-side, as it has to process as the user types out the HTML. I'm going to see if I can browserify the node package.

Comment: Update: html5-lint browserifies just fine, but all it does is make a web service call to https://html5.validator.nu/. What I need is a javascript implementation of that service: https://github.com/validator/validator